# Laravel trait inside transaction

Tags: php, database, laravel, transactions, traits

I am using transactions for DB operations.. here is pseudo code:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

//some logic
//trait function
//some logic

DB::commit();
```

I am communicating with database inside trait function too.. will this function also be inside transaction above?

Comment: Yes it will work. But make sure you are using a try-catch block, so your code will be something like this try { DB::beginTransaction(); ..... code here ..... ; DB::commit(); } catch(Exception $e) { DB::rollback(); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will be. Transactions are looking for db queries and commit them or rollback them but first you have to import your trait in the class you are using transactions.